# Is there a way that I can access the values in the base class using the derived class?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, arguments, virtual

I'm using c++ and i have no idea on how can i access the variables in my base class using the derived class.
I need to get the values in the base class and do an operation in the derived class, since all the functions in the base class contains arguments, when I call the function,

ex:

```
Baseclass.getvalue();
```

i can't put any arguments since it is not defined.

I already did the constructor parts like

```
class derivedclass:baseclass
{
//insert functions here.
};

derivedclass::derivedclass()
     :baseclass()
{
 //insert initialization here
}
```

but i still can't access the values. help? do i need to use virtual? if yes, how?

*this is a user-defined program

Comment: Please show the declaration of values that you wish to access. Remember, they need to be protected or public in order to be accessible to subclasses.

Comment: Give a concrete example of the function, the "value" in the base class, how you try to access it, and what fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply access the (`public` or `protected`) values as if they were part of your derived class.

```
class baseclass {
  protected:
      int m_value;
  public:
       baseclass();
       virtual int getvalue();
};

class derivedclass : public baseclass {
  void dosomething(void) {
     // whoa: `m_value` is part of `baseclass`, and we can simply access it here!
     std::cout << "value: " << m_value << std::endl;

     // we can also use `getvalue()`
     std::cout << "getvalue(): " << getvalue() << std::endl;
  }
};
```

Comment: Providing it is `public` or `protected`, if it is `private`, derived classes will not have access.

Comment: @T.Kiley yes, that's why i mentioned `public` and `protected` in my answer.

Comment: sorry, at time of comment there wasn't :)

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the inheritance is private, so the base subobject and its members are only accessible within the derived class and its friends. By default, members and base classes are private if the class definition is introduced with the `class` keyword, and public with the `struct` keyword. If you want to access them from outside, then you'll need public inheritance:

```
class derivedclass : public baseclass {/*...*/};
```

or

```
struct derivedclass : baseclass  {/*...*/};
```

If the derived class doesn't hide the member by declaring a member with the same name, you can access it as if it were a member of the derived class. (If the inheritance is protected or private, then it will be protected or private within the derived class, and so may not be accessible).

If it is hidden, and you specifically want the base-class version, then you'll need to qualify the member name:

```
Derived.baseclass::getvalue()
```

but if this is the case, then there's something funky going on and the class interfaces probably need rethinking.